# JS 2D constructive solid geometry for canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, csg

Hi I'm writing a part of a web app which creates customised shapes on a 2D canvas and I was wondering how to perform constructive solid geometry using shape coordinates in JS. Are there any pre made libraries I can use for this?

Comment: Stackoverflow deals mainly with coding related questions. So you might ask your question on Stackoverflow's new sister site that deals with software recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: three.js
https://sbcode.net/threejs/csg/